# Does Windows 10 Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) work with Windows Server 2012 R2 Remote Desktop Services (RDS)?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, rds, windows-10

Ever since I upgraded to Windows 10, I've been having issues with RSAT to administer an RDS Windows Server 2012 R2 deployment. At first, the preview of the RSAT tools didn't work well and I chalked it up to being in preview. Now that the RTM version of RSAT came out for Windows 10, though, I'm not sure if it just plain doesn't work, or if it's something I am missing.

I have a large RDS deployment. Load-balanced HA gateway servers, HA connection brokers, and 20+ session hosts. I manage this with Server Manager and some custom PowerShell scripts using RSAT. What I am going to describe works fine from Windows 7 and Windows 8/8.1. In Windows 10, Server Manager sees the deployment, but never actually connects to it and I therefore can't make any changes. The PowerShell scripts that I have to add new session hosts and make changes also fail.

From that, my question is, are the RSAT tools in Windows 10 compatible with Windows Server 2012 R2? Specifically the Remote Desktop Services part, as the rest of the tools seem to be working fine for me.

PS, does anyone know how to connect to multiple deployments that are HA? I have more than one, but Server Manager only lets me have the servers of one deployment at a time, so I constantly have to add/remove servers from the list. At the current moment, I just remote to different servers for each configuration, so that I don't have to keep on configuring Server Manager.